# 18.04: Cura 4.5.0. blanked fields increase with Ubuntu updates

Tags: fonts, screen, installed-programs

My system ran [Cura](https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura) 4.4.1 slicing software perfectly well on Ubuntu 18.04. Cura is started by running an executable appimage downloaded into my home dir.

After several weeks of operation (and without making any Cura or system changes) Cura began to display blank fields.  Areas which would show some menu options became blank and the screen fit was off a little.

It could still be used, most problems were within the top right quarter of the window. The menu options were there and could be selected or dragged to the other side of the screen.

I downloaded Cura 4.5.0 which ran in exactly the same way, but was just usable.

After yesterday's Ubuntu auto system update, the entire Cura window is blank apart from the 3D box which can still be moved around, zoomed etc.

How may I troubleshoot this to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also started having this problem, and looking through several places found [a solution](https://www.networkshinobi.com/cura-in-linux-fontconfig-error/) that worked for me. Basically, the suggestion is to clear out the `~/.cache/qtshadercache` directory. You can do this by running

```
rm /home/karlo/.cache/qtshadercache/*
```

I did this, and it seems to have been rebuilt, with updated values I assume -- and now Cura 4.5.0 is working again! (This is on ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: In the future, please try to add some information from the source in case the linked website goes down. If this happens, your answer may become obsolete/unusable otherwise.